# Casting and MySQL to Postgres migration

Tags: mysql, postgresql

We're in the process of migrating from MySQL to Postgres and have come across a few queries that we're struggling with a little:

MySQL:

`MAX(groups.id) IS NOT NULL AND MIN(groups.parent_id IS NULL) as parent_type`

Postgres:

`(MAX(groups.id) IS NOT NULL AND (MIN((groups.parent_id IS NULL)::int))::bool)::int as parent_type`

The Postgres query works, but is there a way to avoid the explicit casting there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could declare a version of min that works on booleans.

```
Create AGGREGATE min( x boolean )  (
   stype=boolean,
   sfunc=booland_statefunc,
   initcond=true
);
```

or you could just use the `bool_and`  aggregate.

```
MAX(groups.id) IS NOT NULL AND bool_and(groups.parent_id IS NULL) as parent_type
```